# No Class deffinition found jboss: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/kernel/Kernel

Tags: jboss

Hello I am having a problem using jboss from command line, i get the following error:

ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to PreInstall: name=WSKernelLocator state=Real
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/kernel/Kernel

Any reply will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Wow, StackOverflow, jboss forum, *and* the mailing list... you've really covered all the bases with this one :)

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, maybe JBoss archive was not unzipped properly? If you are working on Windows do not use built-in unzipper, it fails for larger archives. Use 7-Zip, WinRar, Total Commander, etc.